# Mysql C connector --- where is source?

Tags: mysql, c, connector

Since Libmysql.dll doesnt come compiled under vs2015 and my program uses that, I am trying to find the source for the C connector (not C++) so I can compile it myself. Research promises that if I download the community edition server, I will find the client source, but I have downloaded any number of zips and not found them. Where are they, please?

Answer (score 5):

I did not found MySQL Github.
There is only C++ connector source code.
But you can download the source code in MySQL official site.
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/
Choose Operating System: Source code

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a part of the server repo itself: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/tree/5.7/libmysql